# ruby on rails call javascript function from button_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, button, onclick

I am trying to perform a very simple task:
Button is clicked - message is displayed (via JavaScript).
Most likely I am either looking in the wrong places or going completely wrong about it but I can't find any examples that will show how to accomplish this simple task.

My js function is:

```
function myAlert() {
     alert ("My Message")
       }
```

The button_tag is:

```
<%= button_tag "Save Changes", :onclick => "myAlert()"%>
```

I would like to know how to properly call the function with `button_tag`, and where this function should be placed in the Rails app, e.g., application.js or some other file.

Comment: Your JS is ok. Do you want a custom message coming from the back office ? An Ajax call to the back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, You are doing it in a right way already. This is a simpler and cleaner way to code. To find javascript easily you should place your js code in `assets/javascripts/[file_name]` where file_name is generated on the bases of your model name by `generate` method of [rails cli](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).